# Bluebird promise loop

Tags: javascript, promise, amazon-dynamodb, bluebird

I am trying to get all records from a DynamoDB table using promises. The problem is that DynamoDB do not return all items in one call I have to make multiple calls.  If LastEvaluatedKey is not null means that I need to make another call with that key to get the remaining records. In my code I am checking that and resolving only after LastEvaluatedKey is null. But the `console.log("done")` is not being executed.

Here is my code:

```
function query(params) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });    
    })
}

function getAllRecords(params, combinedData) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        query(params)
       .then(function(data) {
           if(!combinedData) {
               combinedData = [];
           }
           combinedData.push(data.Items); 
           if(data.LastEvaluatedKey) {
                params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                getAllRecords(params, combinedData)
            }
            else {
                resolve(combinedData);
            }
       })    
   })


}

getAllRecords(params)
.then(function() {
  console.log('done')
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

It's probably a misconception on how promises work from my part. If someone can give me an idea how to make this work. That would be great.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've fallen prey to the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it), in which you are manually constructing promises when you don't need to.

Generally the only time you need to use the `Promise` constructor is when you are converting non-Promise async code to Promise async code. You've already done that in your `query()` function, so you don't need to use the `Promise` constructor in your `getAllRecords()` function.

You should do this instead:

```
function getAllRecords(params) {
    return query(params).then(function (data) {
        var items = [data.Items];

        if(data.LastEvaluatedKey) {
            params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;

            return getAllRecords(params).then(function (theRest) {
                return items.concat(theRest);
            });
        }

        return items;
    });
}
```

Comment: Making this the answer because of the promise antipattern. Thanks